# SEO-Friendly URLs (Apache)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've looked around for quite a while now, and cannot seem to find a working solution. I wish to redirect

```
http://dynamic-domain/test/$2y$06$BzlNRGts.MeebBMj98w7aeabu0Xc1brxG5i47AWtOcnsu1ijXQaXO
```

to

```
http://dynamic-domain/test.php?aid=$2y$06$BzlNRGts.MeebBMj98w7aeabu0Xc1brxG5i47AWtOcnsu1ijXQaXO
```

The tid parameter is random, and will not be that exact string. That's an example.

I cannot get it to work. I don't have much experience with this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) test.php?aid=$1
```

You match the test folder and then capture anything after that. Use the `$1` variable to refer to the first captured group.

Comment: Still not parsing the aid get parameter to the test.php file.